# xcode 4/phonegap does not display jquery mobile correctly

Tags: jquery, xcode4, jquery-mobile, cordova

I can't figure out why jquerymobile does not correctly display in xCode4's i0s simulator using cordova.  I reference all the script source as per my directory.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
```

Full code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <!-- iPad/iPhone specific css below, add after your main css >
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />       
    -->
    <!-- If your application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*default cordova code which is too long to display but it contains the onBodyLoad()*/
    </script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
      <div data-role="page" data-theme="a"> 
          <div data-role="header"> 
              <h1> Header Content </h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content"> 
              <p> Main Page Content </p>
          </div>
          <div data-role="footer"> 
              <h1> Footer Content </h1>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also followed phonegap's tutorial but jquerymobile buttons, lists, etc. still do not display properly.

Comment: You should consider updating jQuery mobile - they're on 1.2 now. There have been many improvements and fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery 1.7.2 is incompatible with jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 (read jquery 1.7.2 release notes!)

Either use js 1.7.2 with jqmobile 1.1 RC1, or
jq 1.7.1 with jq mobile 1.0.1

Comment: Thank you!!!!  I also removed the "/" before "jquery" in <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />